# Missing Dictonairy key from my Tweepy steam

Tags: python, json, dictionary, jupyter-notebook, tweepy

I've been using tweepy API in Jupiter notebook to pull tweets saving them to a JSON file, however, the `'text'` key is condensed and cuts off the full tweet. In the screenshot I've attached you can see in the red box the key for `'extended_text'` however when I run `tweets[0].keys()` is does not appear. I tried running `tweets[0]['extended_text']` but no luck.

If I open the JSON file with notepad I am able to find the 'extended_text' key and the formatting appears correct. perhaps I handled the file wrong? [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zdo4w.png)